# How to plot straight lines at only discrete data

Tags: matlab, plot

I have discrete data and I would like to connect them via straight lines. For example,

```
x = 0:0.2:1;
y = 0:0.2:1;
plot(x,y, 'LineWidth', 2)
grid
```

The result is

[image]

The expected result is

[image]

Is there a command for achieving the above picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `arrayfun` to repeat the `plot` for each two sets:

```
x = 0:0.2:1;
y = 0:0.2:1;
figure;hold on;
plot(x,y, '-o','LineWidth', 2);
arrayfun(@(xx,yy)plot([xx xx],[0 yy],'r'),x,y)
arrayfun(@(xx,yy)plot([0 xx],[yy yy],'r'),x,y)
grid on;
```

[image]